# Não funciona o "SoapWrapper" com laravel

Tags: laravel, web-service, soap

Estou tentando consumir um WS através de aplicação em laravel 5.6.

Esse é o código do teste:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use SoapClient;
use Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facades\SoapWrapper;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Soap\Request\GetConversionAmount;
use App\Soap\Response\GetConversionAmountResponse;
use App\Soap;
use App\Soap\Response;

class EducacionalController extends Controller{

protected $soapWrapper;

public function index(Request $request){
    $soap = SoapWrapper::add(function ($service) {
        $service
            ->name('rmFametro')
            ->wsdl('http://sistemas.portaledu.com.br:8051/wsConsultaSQL/MEX?wsdl')
            ->options([
                'login' => 'YYYYYYYY',
                'password' => 'XXXXXXXX'
            ])
            ->trace(true);
    });

     $response = $soap->soapWrapper->call('RealizarConsultaSQL', [
        'codSentenca' => '07', 
        'codColigada' => '1', 
        'codSistema'  => 'S', 
        'parameters'  => 'CPF=99999999999',
    ]);

    var_dump($response);

    }
}
```

E esse é o erro do teste:

> Undefined property: Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Wrapper::$soapWrapper

Minhas configurações, no aap.php:

```
'providers' => [
...
Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\ServiceProvider::class,
...
];
```

.

```
 'aliases' => [
 ...
 'SoapWrapper' => Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facades\SoapWrapper::class
 ...     
 ];
```

[image: Erro que obtenho hoje]

Onde não consigo ver erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique os comentários

```
//instancie um novo objecto
$soap = new SoapWrapper; 


//estava a  faltar o primeiro parâmetro 'rmFametro'
$soap->add('rmFametro', function ($service) {
    $service->wsdl('http://sistemas.portaledu.com.br:8051/wsConsultaSQL/MEX?wsdl')
        ->options([
            'login' => 'YYYYYYYY',
            'password' => 'XXXXXXXX'
        ])
        ->trace(true);
});

//verifique a forma correcta de efectuar a chamada
$response = $soap->call('rmFametro.RealizarConsultaSQL', [
    'codSentenca' => '07',
    'codColigada' => '1',
    'codSistema' => 'S',
    'parameters' => 'CPF=99999999999',
]);

var_dump($response);
```

Atualização utilizando ***Controller***

adicione o *service provider* em app/config/app.php.

```
Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\ServiceProvider::class,
```

adicione *alias* em app/config/app.php.

```
'SoapWrapper' => Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facade\SoapWrapper::class,
```

EducacionalController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\SoapWrapper;

class EducacionalController extends Controller
{
    protected $soapWrapper;

    public function __construct(SoapWrapper $soapwrapper)
    {
        $this->soapWrapper = $soapwrapper;
    }
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $this->soapWrapper->add('rmFametro', function ($service) {
            $service->wsdl('http://sistemas.portaledu.com.br:8051/wsConsultaSQL/MEX?wsdl')
                ->options([
                    'login' => 'YYYYYYYY',
                    'password' => 'XXXXXXXX'
                ])
                ->trace(true);
        });

        $response = $this->soapWrapper->call('rmFametro.RealizarConsultaSQL', [
            'codSentenca' => '07',
            'codColigada' => '1',
            'codSistema' => 'S',
            'parameters' => 'CPF=99999999999',
        ]);

        var_dump($response);

    }

}
```

Comment: Erro ao tentar instanciar: SoapWrapper. `syntax error, unexpected '$soap' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)`

Comment: Usou o meu código ou adaptou ?

Comment: O meu está a devolver "Usuário ou Senha inválidos! O usuário ou senha utilizados para login não são válidos para acesso ao sistema. Verifique se o código do usuário está digitado corretamente e redigite sua senha. Verifique se a tecla CAPS LOCK não está pressionada acidentalmente."

Comment: Só adaptei onde tem: usuário e senha. o resto está igual, você poderia disponibilizar a classe completa?

Comment: só coloquei dentro de uma closure dentro de uma Route ex. Route::get('/', function () { 'aqui'})

Comment: Qual o erro que está obtendo

Comment: Irei coloque um complemento na pergunta, com ima imagem que ilustra o erro!

Comment: Veja a resposta atualizada

Comment: Para instanciar um novo SoapWrapper deve utilizar o construtor

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80957/discussion-between-milrak-pereira-pessoa-and-jorge-costa).